# How to change the following output into a proper string?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to code a chatbot that will print a string containing `n` times the first letter of my name, followed by `"n"` and then followed by `n-1` times the second letter in my name.

Example:

```
name: chris
n = 5 (since there are 5 letters in the name)
n-1 = 4
first letter of the name: c
second letter of the name: h
```

The string I want to generate: `ccccc5hhhh`

My problem: The string generated is in brackets which I don't want. I want the string to be exactly as "ccccc5hhhh", no spaces; all in one line, but I keep getting `['c','c','c','c','c']5['h','h','h','h']` as the output.

```
st1 = input("First name? ==> ")

print("Please enter the first letter of your name")
letter = input ("First letter? ==>? ")

if (letter == st1[0]):
    # initializing list of lists
    test_list = st1[0]
    test_list1 = st1[1]

# repeat letters n times
res =  [ele for ele in test_list for i in range(len(st1))]
res2 =  [ele for ele in test_list1 for i in range(len(st1)-1)]

# printing result
print(str(res), len(st1), str(res2))
```

Comment: Note that `test_list` and `test_list1` are strings.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of converting your lists into string you can use the `.join()` function, like so `''.join(res)`

So you final line should be:

```
print(''.join(res) + str(len(st1)) + ''.join(res2))
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result I get now is ccccc 5 hhhh. I want to know how to make it ccccc5hhhh

Comment: @harold232 use print(''.join(res) + str(len(st1)) + ''.join(res2)) without the commas.

Comment: The '+' operator appends the strings, and str( ) casts len(st1) to be a string.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function. Using `,` with your arguments will insert a space though.

To get the result you are looking for you will want:

```py
print(''.join(res) + str(len(st1)) + ''.join(res2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating this. Just use string multiplication.

```
s = 'chris'
n = len(s)
res1 = s[0] * n
res2 = s[1] * (n - 1)
print(res1 + str(n) + res2)  # -> ccccc5hhhh
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to python, do you know why my result generated the "[]" brackets when i didn't even include it in the print function

Comment: @harold232 Yes, `res` and `res2` are lists in your code, so they're printed as lists.

Comment: @harold232 Lists are printed very literally. Note what's printed when you do `print([1, 2, 3])`. Most standard Python structures are printed as their literals are written.

Comment: Also, do you know how to make the ccccc5hhhh in all capital letters like CCCCC5HHHH? I tried putting .isupper() beside res1 and res2 in the print function but it causes an error.

Comment: @harold232 [`str.upper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper)

Comment: where do i type str.upper() beside to. Nvm figured it out